# How to pick minus except of two tables in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two tables one of which include ids from the other one. How can I choose all the records from the first table that`s ids are not in the second table using RoR query interface?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
ModelOne.where.not(id: ModelTwo.ids)
```

Comment: No, their id columns do not match, id of first Model is a content of an integer column of other one.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Please explain better by updating your question with examples.